# Printing out an array in C without a predetermined length

Tags: c, arrays

I'd like to print out an entire array in C. I've tried using `sizeof` to determine the length of the array in order to print it with a for loop, but it didn't work and returned an error. What did I do incorrectly, and else can I try?

```
// The items in the array are determined by user input
int length = (sizeof(my_array) / sizeof( my_array[0])) + 1;
    printf("%d\n", length);
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(my_array) / sizeof( my_array[0])) + 1; i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: where is `my_array` defined?  also, "returned an error" is not specific enough to offer more ideas.  big picture: if an array does not have a predetermined length, then you will need to keep track of the size on your own.

Comment: Create a [mcve] for your problem. Currently answer is "it depends".

Comment: However, note that `sizeof` returns size of the *type* of the expression in it. If `my_array` type does not depend on user input, it will not be useful.

Comment: It will only work in the scope within which `my_array` was declared, otherwise `my_array` is converted to a pointer to its first element and `sizeof (my_array)` is simply `sizeof (a_pointer)`, [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is accessing data beyond the end of the array. This lead to undefined behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior.

You are calculating the number of elements of the array and are adding 1. You need to remove the + 1, so that it looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(my_array) / sizeof( my_array[0])); i++)
```

I just modified you code a little bit and made a self-containing example out of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *my_array[] = {"abc", "def"};
    int length = (sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]));
    printf("%d\n", length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following out to the console:

```
2
abc
def
```

So all elements are printed when removing + 1.

Comment: your example uses an array with a predetermined size

Comment: It's self-containing example to illustrate that the code of OP is accessing the array beyond the end of the array leading to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line of code:

```
int length = sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(int); //if the array is type int
```

Use whatever the data type of the array instead of int

Comment: The problem being that if `my_array` was not declared in the current scope (e.g if it was passed as a parameter to a function), then you simply have `sizeof (a_pointer)/sizeof (an_int)`